# Hide a tag if mailto or tel doesn't exist

Tags: jquery, css

I have a database powered staff profile system, they can enter their details and it will generate a HTML page.
They can enter an email address and phone number and the output HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="mailto:[Email]" class="teamEmail">Email</a><br />
<a href="tel:[Phone]" class="teamPhone">[Phone]</a>
```

I have some CSS that will hide an empty HREF here:

```
a.social[href='']{ display:none; }
```

But what I would like to achieve is to hide the a tag if there is no content after the mailto: or tel:, the CSS above will not hide the a tag as the mailto and tel both display inside the href.

I assume this would have to be handled with jQuery which i'm OK with because one function may hide both the mailto and tel.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just not output the `a` tag on the server side?

Comment: Unfortunately the database is handled inside of a CMS and I have no control server side, it needs to be hidden front end.

Comment: The database being handled by a CMS is not a great reason in and of itself. What kind of CMS doesn't support templating?

Comment: Not relevant to my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
a.social[href='mailto:'],
a.social[href='tel:'] { 
     display:none; 
}
```

It only targets links with specifically "mailto:" or "tel:". If there is more than those specific strings then the element will not be targeted.